# Is the following combinatorial identity true?

Tags: combinatorics, complex-numbers

Let $\omega=\cos\frac{2\pi}{3}+i\sin\frac{2\pi}{3}=e^{2\pi i/3}.$ Is it true that

${n \choose 2} - {n \choose 5} + {n \choose 8}-{n \choose 11}+\dots=\frac{1}{3}\left(\omega(1-\omega)^n+\omega^2(1-\omega^2)^n \right)$?

If not, can you please help me find the correct identity? Thank you!

To find the above equality I simply used the binomial expansions for $(1-1)^n$, $(1-\omega)^n$, $(1-\omega^2)^n$ and treated these as a system of equations.

Sketch of my proof:

By expanding,
$$(1-\omega)^n={n \choose 0}-{n \choose 1}\omega+{n \choose 2}\omega^2-{n\choose 3}\omega^3+\dots$$
Since $\omega^3=1$, we get
\begin{multline*}
(1-\omega)^n=\left({n \choose 0}-{n \choose 3}+{n\choose 6}-\dots\right)-\omega\left({n \choose 1}-{n \choose 4}+{n\choose 7}-\dots\right)\\
+\omega^2\left({n \choose 2}-{n \choose 5}+{n\choose 8}-\dots\right).
\end{multline*}

Let's make some notations for these 3 sums so that
$$(1-\omega)^n=S_1-\omega S_2+\omega^2S_3.$$

Similarily,
$$(1-\omega^2)^n=S_1-\omega^2S_2+\omega S_3$$
and
$$(1-1)^n=S_1-S_2+S_3$$

Viewing these three equalities as a system of 3 equations in $(S_1,S_2,S_3)$ we can deduce that

$$S_3=\frac{1}{3}\left(\omega(1-\omega)^n+\omega^2(1-\omega^2)^n \right).$$

I don't know what's wrong since fleablood's answer clearly proves the identity is not true.

Comment: Sorry. I think I wrote the identity wrong. I edited it.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that $n\equiv 2 \pmod 3$.

Comment: See [OEIS A057083](https://oeis.org/A057083) offset  so $\tfrac23 3^{n/2} \cos\left(\tfrac{n-4}{6}\pi\right)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem like it might be. Let's find out.

$w(1 - w)^n = \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^n{n\choose k}w^{k+1}$ while

$w^2(1-w^2)^n = \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^n{n\choose k}(w^{k+1})^2$ so

$\frac 13(w(1-w)^n + w^2(1-w^2)n) = \frac 13(\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k{n\choose k}[w^{k+1}+(w^{k+1})^2]$

And $k\equiv -1 \pmod 3$ then $w^{k+1} = 1; (w^{k+1})^2 = 1$ and $w^{k+1}+(w^{k+1})^2=2$

And if $k\equiv 0 \pmod 3$ then $w^{k+1}= -\frac 12 + i\frac {\sqrt 3}2$ and $(w^{k+1})^2 = -\frac 12 - i\frac {\sqrt 3}2$ and $w^{k+1}+(w^{k+1})^2 = -1$.

And if $k\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ then $w^{k+1}= -\frac 12 - i\frac {\sqrt 3}2$ and $(w^{k+1})^2 = -\frac 12 + i\frac {\sqrt 3}2$ and $w^{k+1}+(w^{k+1})^2 = -1$.

So

$\frac 13(w(1-w)^n + w^2(1-w^2)n) = \frac 13(\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k{n\choose k}[w^{k+1}+(w^{k+1})^2]) =$

$\frac 13(\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k{n\choose k}\begin{cases}2&k\equiv -1\pmod 3\\-1&otherwise\end{cases}=$

$\frac 13(\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \frac n3\rfloor}(-1)^j[-{n\choose 3j} +2{n\choose {3j+1}}-{n\choose {3j+2}}]+\frac 13\sum_{k=3\lfloor \frac n3\rfloor+1}^n (-1)^k{n\choose k}\begin{cases}2&k\equiv -1\pmod 3\\-1&otherwise\end{cases}$

So your equation seems to be assuming $n\equiv 2\pmod 3$.  We'll ignore that.

Now you seem to be claiming that $[-{n\choose 3j} +2{n\choose {3j+1}}-{n\choose {3j+2}}]={n\choose 3j + 2}$ and if we can verify that we are done.

Let $3j+1 = m$ and we can rewrite the claim as

$2 {n\choose m} - {n\choose m-1} -{n\choose m+1} = {n\choose m+1}$ or

$2 {n\choose m} - {n\choose m-1} = 2{n\choose m+1}$.

The LHS is $\frac {2n!}{m!(n-m)!}-\frac {n!}{(m+1)!(n-m-1)!}=$

$\frac {n!(2(m+1) -\frac 1{n-m})}{(m+1)!(n-m)!}$

While the RHS is $\frac {n!}{(m+1)!(n-m-1)!}=\frac {n!(n-m)}{(m+1)(n-m)!}$

And as $2(m+1) - \frac 1{n-m} \ne n-m$ this identity does not seem to hold.

Unless I made a mistake which is very possible.

Comment: I'll attach my method of finding the desired sum in the original question. Thank you for taking your time and showing me why my identity was wrong.